# ArcPy / ArcMap 10.2: How to report data to user?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-addin

I'm developing an arcpy addin with ArcMap 10.2 that outputs a feature layer based on user input.

How can I display attributes from this layer in a MessageBox or other reporting mechanism?

I don't want to enable data driven pages, so dynamic tables don't seem to be an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pythonaddins` is limited in reporting and displaying attributes to users. `pythonaddins` ***is mainly a way to offer python developers a way to interact with user events***. That being said the main mechanism for a developer to display messages to the user is through `pythonaddins.MessageBox`.

This function takes in a message formatted as a string as the first argument, a title, and a mb_type code which refers to the type of message box, i.e. OK only, Yes/No, Retry/Cancel, etc. You could feed in the attributes you would like to report in a formatted string as the first argument to `pythonaddins.MessageBox()` to report back to the user.

Here is a real quick (and sort of sloppy string formatting) example of feeding in an extent object and reporting this info back to the user, if you would like more code please let me know:

```
            rasterObject = arcpy.Raster(inRaster)
            rasterSpatialRef = rasterObject.spatialReference
            rasterExtent = arcpy.Describe(rasterObject).extent              

            hillShadeBoolean = pythonaddins.MessageBox('\t\t' + 'Top: ' + str(rasterExtent.YMax) + '\n\n' +
                                                       'Left: ' + str(rasterExtent.XMin) + '\t\t\t' +
                                                       'Right: ' + str(rasterExtent.XMax) + '\n\n' + 
                                                       '\t\t' + 'Bottom: ' + str(rasterExtent.YMin) + '\n\n' +
                                                       'Spatial Reference: ' + rasterSpatialRef.name + '\n' +
                                                       'Units: ' + rasterSpatialRef.linearUnitName + '\n\n' +
                                                       'Would you like to create a hillshade for this raster?\n',
                                                       'Raster Extent',
                                                       4)
```

`pythonaddins` is really a python module of only five functions although you are limited in what you can do it can still be quite powerful. [Click here for more info from ESRI's documentation on the pythonaddins module](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/The_pythonaddins_module/014p00000021000000).

Comment: I'll have to look at that one.. I use PyWin, mostly because it comes with a good editor with some InteliSense but partly because it has a basic message box. The pythonaddins message box looks more flexible.